# Featured Image not displaying

Tags: images

I upload a photo for a featured image in about page but this featured image is not displaying. What's the problem on that?

My site http://goo.gl/hsN9TE

Comment: Make sure your content-page.php have `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`. If your theme does not have content-page.php then check in page.php.

Comment: I check both page.php and content-page.php and there's no <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> hmm

Comment: Then try it by adding `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` in either one of these files. Adding in both file will make featured image appear 2 times.

Comment: It will appear at the top of title page?

Comment: [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/165880/edit) your question and post your code for what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454205/how-can-i-add-thumbnail-to-recent-post-wordpress/26467188#26467188

In addition to the `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` (where you include this is where the image will appear), you have to make sure your theme has post thumbnails support. This needs to be in your theme function file: `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`.